# How to uset a FA Kit in a Blazor Server Side app

Tags: font-awesome, blazor-server-side

I'd like to know how to use a KIT from FontAwesome in a Server-Side Blazor Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to accomplish this is by using FA CSS and font files. Using the kit is not possible. Here is my setup:

[image: FontAwesome 5 Setup in Blazor]